# Postfix and dovecot auto create email alias

Tags: php, sql, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

Good day, 
Im still a noobie when it comes to webservers using dovecot and postfix, I have created a webserver before to control the mail, but just set up a email alias etc.. 
Ive been asked now if it is possible to create those dovecot "pods" automatically? So is it possible for instance that when a user register's through the website and gives the alias wanted, That some sort of PHP script will import those details from the form or site maybe into a SQL table, that then the server can pick up if the table has been updated, and then will use that info to automatically create the "pods" for dovecot and postfix? Like i said this is all new to me, but any information on what steps it would take or how to go about this or the way it would work, will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Dovecot's Wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo), there are howtos that explain how you can setup dovecot with **virtual users**. You can use MySQL as a backend for this and you can use Postfix as delivery agent.